# Run Python function in Flutter app using Chaquopy gives error about function not defined

Tags: python, flutter, dart, chaquopy

I've got the Chaquopy Flutter example working in my Flutter app. This involves calling the Python code from the Flutter app via [the provided `script.py`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D4Hjt66f0MXkaeAQ8WLX3DEebX3BrFvM/view).

```dart
  final _result = await Chaquopy.executeCode("print('hello')");
  print("Python output: $_result");
```

However, when I try to run my own Python function `hello` that I have added to `script.py`, it is unable to find that function!

```dart
  final _result = await Chaquopy.executeCode("hello('world')");
  print("Python output: $_result");
```

will give the output:

```
Python output: {textOutputOrError: name 'hello' is not defined
}
```

Here's my `script.py`

```py
import io,os,sys,time,threading,ctypes,inspect,traceback

def _async_raise(tid, exctype):
    tid = ctypes.c_long(tid)
    if not inspect.isclass(exctype):
        exctype = type(exctype)
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, ctypes.py_object(exctype))
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("invalid thread id")
    elif res != 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, None)
        raise SystemError("Timeout Exception")

def stop_thread(thread):
    _async_raise(thread.ident, SystemExit)
    
def text_thread_run(code):
    try:
        env={}
        exec(code, env, env)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    
# MY NEWLY ADDED FUNCTION
def hello(text):
    print(f"hello {text}")
    
#   This is the code to run Text functions...
def mainTextCode(code):
    global thread1
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=text_thread_run, args=(code,),daemon=True)
    thread1.start()
    timeout = 15 # change timeout settings in seconds here...
    thread1_start_time = time.time()
    while thread1.is_alive():
        if time.time() - thread1_start_time > timeout:
            stop_thread(thread1)
            raise TimeoutError
        time.sleep(1)
```

What is the correct way to call my own function that I define inside `script.py`? Even better is to have my functions defined in another file at the same directory level as `script.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import script
script.hello('world')
```

To pass multiple lines of code to `Chaquopy.executeCode`, separate them with newlines.

Other Python files in the same directory can be accessed in the same way.